# How to format a list of lists?

Tags: lists, enumitem

So I'm not really certain what to call this situation, but I need a list that looks a bit like this:

```
 Ia. Foo
  b. Bar
  c. Baz
IIa. Foo
  b. Bar
  ...
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this with the `enumitem` package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more information in terms of list adjustments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{outernum}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{innernum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[outernum]{label={\Roman*},labelsep=0pt,itemindent=0pt,align=right,labelwidth=0pt,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[innernum]{label={\alph*.},labelsep=0pt,align=left,itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{outernum}
  \item
  \begin{innernum}
    \item An item
    \item An item
    \item An item
  \end{innernum}
  \item
  \begin{innernum}
    \item An item
    \item An item
    \item An item
  \end{innernum}
\end{outernum}

\end{document}
```